# How to implement Accessibility in Desktop Compose

Tags: kotlin, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

I am building an app with [Desktop Compose Multiplatform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/) for Windows and MacOS platform.
I need to add accessibility support for users.

In Android we have `Accessibility Scanner` and `TalkBack` to announce `contentDescription` and these tools also helps with suggestions related to sizing and alignment of UI elements.

But there are no official documentation / tutorials / support for Accessibility in Desktop Compose.

This [issue ID 1336](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/1366) is registered but not valid outcome.

1 How do I implement support for Accessibility in Desktop Compose. Kindly advice.
2. How the content Description can be announced to the readers
3. How to perform Accessibility Scanner, the way we can do in Android with tool `Accessibility Scanner`

Comment: not sure what answer you expect to get here, there is no one more knowledgeable than the maintainers of the linked repository.

Comment: Have you checked [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility)? Compose Desktop does not add much to this topic, as you can see [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Accessibility).